# How do I know if my site is using the xmlrpc.php file?

Tags: xml-rpc

I have taken over a website where I work that was developed by a previous employee, it seems that recently this site has been the victim of a string of DDoS attacks through the use of the xmlrpc pingback proven by log entries like this:

`154.16.63.40 - - [22/May/2016:06:52:49 +0100] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 596 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`
 (Obviously this isn't a google bot because there is no reason for google to post to this file.)

I believe there are many solutions to this ([This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-wordpress-from-xml-rpc-attacks-on-ubuntu-14-04)) but I tend to lean towards just outright blocking access to the file. However I am unsure as to whether this site is actually using the service xmlrpc allows you to use. Is there any particular way I can check if the previous developer has put anything in place to use wordpress xmlrpc functionality? Could I check for functions in specific files/is there anything that screams out to identify the use?

any help with this would be great!

**EDIT:** Would something like this be helpful?

```
<FilesMatch "^(xmlrpc\.php)">
    Order Deny,Allow
    # IP address Whitelist
    Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

If I allow from the ip address of the server would this work for plugins etc or do they all have their own IP address that would need to be added?

Comment: XML-RPC API can be used by clients, for example the WordPress mobile apps. How do you know all IPs to be whitelisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a spam bot or an enumeration rather than a DDoS attack. To be sure, you should look into your resource consumption, the dynamic of IP addresses and maybe the payloads.

**1. Blocking access to `xmlrpc.php` file.**:

I think you shouldn't:

1. It cannot help you [survive a real DDoS attack](https://serverfault.com/questions/531941/i-am-under-ddos-what-can-i-do).
2. As [@cybmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37428/cybmeta) said, it might break many third party services.
3. Allow access from certain IPs also doesn't help because IP can be faked and you cannot list all IPs which will use XML-RPC service.

I often log all IPs which make requests to `xmlrpc.php`, use iptables to setup rate limit. Then, block IPs which are surely evil.

**2. How to know if your site is using `xmlrpc.php`**

1. Functions and resources in WordPress which use XML-RPC service have `xmlrpc` string in functions' name or files' name so you can skim through your theme and plugins to check if there're any matches.
2. All XML-RPC requests in WordPress go through `xmlrpc.php` which `define('XMLRPC_REQUEST', true)` so you can use:

```
if ( defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) {
    // Log something.
    // Or exit immediately if something is evil in the request.
}
```

Note that you cannot use the code in theme/plugin files. `xmlrpc.php` is independent from themes and plugins so you must put it in your `wp-config.php` file.

Answer (score 3):

As you have described, you has been victim of a DDoS attack (or maybe not, I just assume you know it). Those types of attack can be against any part of a dynamic website, for example the index.php or xml-rpc.php files.

From my point of view, **the right solution is not to block the attacked part but to block the attacker**.

So, do not block the XML-RPC API in WrodPress, it is used by a large number of plugins and external clients; block it only if you really know what you are doing and its consequences. Instead block the attacker at server level, for example you could blacklist the attacker's IP in a server firewall or .htaccess.

Comment: This is something I am already doing however if an attacker is persistent they will just simply change the ip address they are using to one that I haven't had the chance to block yet and then the list will grow ever longer without actually solving the problem at its core.

Comment: And if the attacker goes against index.php, what would you do? The solution is a firewall, not to block the scripts used by your website. Anyway, block XML-PC API if you know what you are doing and you don't need it. Unfortunately I can not answer your question about "How to know if I need XML-RPC".